# PyQt4 PostgreSQL QSqlQuery BC information loss

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt, pyqt4, qsqlquery

PyQt4 PostgreSQL QSqlQuery BC information loss

I am programming with PyQt4 and PostgreSQL, and I have a problem
reading dates before Christ (BC). With psql, all is OK:

```
# SELECT id, born, givname FROM person WHERE id=100000;
   id   |     born      | givname 
--------+---------------+---------
 100000 | 0428-01-01 BC | Plato
(1 row)
```

But it seems the sign of the year, i.e. BC/AD information,
is lost somewhere on the way from the PostgreSQL server
to the PyQt QSqlQuery class.

see this Python code snippet:

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlQuery
sql = 'SELECT born FROM person WHERE id=100000'
query = QSqlQuery(sql)
query.next()
v = query.value(0)
print "v:", v
print "type:", type(v)
print "typename:", v.typeName()
d = v.toDate()
print "valid:", d.isValid()
print "d:", d, d.toString()
print 'dd.MM.yyyy:', d.toString('dd.MM.yyyy')
print "year:", d.year() # should be negative
print "toPyDate:", d.toPyDate()
print "toJulianDay:", d.toJulianDay()
```

output:

```
v: <PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0xb216cd84>
type: <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant'>
typename: QDate
valid: True
d: PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(428, 1, 1) So. Jan 1 428
dd.MM.yyyy: 01.01.0428
year: 428
toPyDate: 0428-01-01
toJulianDay: 1877385
```

Question:
Where is the BC information lost and how can I get it?

Answers to the posters' questions:

What is the actual julian day integer value that is stored in the datebase?

```
volker=# SELECT id, born, extract(julian from born), givname FROM person WHERE id=100000;
   id   |     born      | date_part | givname 
--------+---------------+-----------+---------
 100000 | 0428-01-01 BC |   1565102 | Plato
```

In PostgreSQL: (www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html)
Julian Day (days since November 24, 4714 BC at midnight)
PostgreSQL returns 0 for SELECT EXTRACT(JULIAN FROM '4714-11-24 BC'::DATE);

Qt has a different definition for Julian day.
From pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdate.html#fromJulianDay:
"The range of valid dates is from January 2nd, 4713 BCE, ...".
(Maybe that's the difference between the proleptic Julian Calendar and 
the proleptic Gregorian Calendar, as in the post by ekhumoro.)

Note that January 1st, 4713 BCE seems not to be considered valid:

```
>>> j1 = QDate.fromJulianDay(1)
>>> print j1.getDate()
(-4713, 1, 2)
>>> print j1.toString()
Di. Jan 2 -4713
>>> j0 = QDate.fromJulianDay(0)
>>> print j0.toString()

>>> print j0.getDate()
(-4713, 1, 1)
```

But what is the actual value stored in the database?
I don't know what the server stores internally, I only take 
as a reference what it passes to the psql client, 
and that seems to be an ISO date string,
format YYYY-MM-DD, with ' BC' appended for BC years.
By the way, reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years
it seems BC notation is not ISO, but a year sign is.
That leads to the next question: Can I configure the server so it 
yields '-0428-01-01' instead of '0428-01-01 BC'?

Comment: What is the actual julian day integer value that is stored in the datebase? It should be 1565097. This is the only [datatype](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-types.html#postgresql-data-types) that Qt will automatically convert to a `QDate`. It's hard to see why it would get that wrong, since it must use `QDate.fromJulianDay()` to do the conversion (and that does produce a `QDate` with a negative year as expected).

Comment: @ekhumoro `select extract(julian from '0428-01-01 BC'::date)` returns `1565102`

Comment: But what is the **actual value** stored in the database? Is it a string or an integer? If the database stores the date as a string, then that could explain the problem, since Qt cannot parse the "BC/AD" part. And note that `QDate.fromJulianDay(1565102)` gives `QDate(-428, 1, 6)`, which differs from the output shown in your question. Qt uses the proleptic Julian Calendar for dates prior to 4 October 1582, whereas PostgreSQL uses the proleptic Gregorian Calendar.

Comment: @ekumoro It is up to `QSqlQuery` to retrieve the query result as text or binary: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html

Comment: @ekhumoro Dates are stored as 4 bytes integers: http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: When I asked for the actual value, I am not talking about the specifics of the PostgreSQL implementation. I obviously know what those are, since I've already explained all that in my previous comments. If Qt receives integer dates, there's no problem interpreting BC/AD (that's the whole point of using julian days). But if Qt receives strings, there is no way to interpret BC/AD, because it only recognizes ISO dates in the range 0-9999. It cannot parse negative years or "BC/AD" suffixes.

Comment: PS: previously, I assumed Qt could automatically convert PostgreSQL dates using `fromJulianDay()`. However, after looking at the Qt source code, that appears not to be the case. So if you want to distinguish BC/AD dates, it seems you must do the conversion yourself. If you start from integer values, you will need to allow for the difference between proleptic Julian (Qt) vs proleptic Gregorian (PostgreSQL) dates. If you start from strings, you will need to parse out the "BC/AD" suffix and then modify the year value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's more a workaround than a solution, 
but as ekhumoro suggested, I can retrieve the date
as a string (resp. TEXT in PostgreSQL), simply like this:

```
SELECT born::TEXT FROM person WHERE id=100000;
```

giving the result:

```
0428-01-01 BC
```

as string which I can parse for the BC suffix.

Using integer values is also possible, but then I have to deal with the difference between proleptic Julian (Qt) vs proleptic Gregorian (PostgreSQL) dates, which seems more complicated.